# Oracle : Update row based on a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the data in following way:

```
ORDER_NO  FULFILL_ID  SOURCE_LOC   ITEM 
  100                    11001     0021
  100                    11001     0031
  100                    12001     0014
  100                    13001     0053
```

Whenever the source_loc is same, it should give the same fulfill_id.
The IDs should start from 1 and increment by 1.. So the data should be update as

```
ORDER_NO  FULFILL_ID  SOURCE_LOC   ITEM 
  100         1           11001     0021
  100         1           11001     0031
  100         2           12001     0014
  100         3           13001     0053
```

How do I update the column?

Comment: Do you want to store that FULFILL_ID  value in the table? That's a bit dangerous, that's how you get data inconsistency when a row is inserted/updated/deleted. Create a view instead. (Or use triggers.)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a single MERGE statement:

```
merge into orders o
using
(
  select order_no, 
         dense_rank() over (order by source_loc) as rn, 
         source_loc, 
         item
  from orders
) t on (o.order_no = t.order_no and o.item = t.item and o.source_loc = t.source_loc)
when matched then update 
  set fullfill_id = rn;
```

The question is: why do you need to save this information, if this can easily be calculated at runtime.

You can create a view like this:

```
create or replace view orders_2
as
select order_no, 
       dense_rank() over (order by source_loc) as fullfill_id, 
       source_loc, 
       item
from orders
```

Comment: The data being provided has this column as null. 
So this needs to be populated manually.

Comment: @ImranHemani. What i'm trying to say is that you don't need to _store_ it at all.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.. but that's what client requires.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it matters, but if new records come in with the same `source_loc` field and you want to ensure they preserve and inherit the previously assigned value for `fulfill_id` then something like this might work to make sure previous IDs are inherited and new ids are assigned:

```
update mytable t1
set t1.fulfill_id = (
  with already as (
    select distinct source_loc, fulfill_id
    from mytable
    where fulfill_id is not null
  ),
  final_id as (
    select distinct
      m.source_loc,
      coalesce (a.fulfill_id, dense_rank() over (order by m.source_loc)) as fulfill_id    
    from
      mytable m,
      already a
    where
      m.source_loc = a.source_loc (+)
  )
  select
    f.fulfill_id
  from final_id f
  where
    f.source_loc = t1.source_loc
)
where t1.fulfill_id is null;
```

In this manner, once a fulfill_id is assigned to a source_loc, it's retained.  Data that started like this:

```
ORDER_NO  FULFILL_ID  SOURCE_LOC   ITEM 
  100         1           11001     0021
  100         1           11001     0031
  100         2           12001     0014
  100         3           13001     0053
  100                     12001     0014
  100                     10001     0014
```

Would end up like this:

```
ORDER_NO  FULFILL_ID  SOURCE_LOC   ITEM 
  100         1           11001     0021
  100         1           11001     0031
  100         2           12001     0014
  100         3           13001     0053
  100         2           12001     0014
  100         4           10001     0014
```